# How to show particular single row item onclick of listview item along with previous / next button in android?

Tags: android

I have two activities A and B.

In A activity, i am showing all records in `listview`. When user clicks on any of the items listed on Activity A, it should redirected to next Activity B and it should have displayed that particular single item along with Next/Previous button.

When user clicks on Next or Previous button, the item should be changed accordingly.

Should I use `listview` or simply textview to display particular records on Activity B which changes onclick of Previous/Next. How to achieve that ?

Please help me out.
Here is my Activity A

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_giga);
     StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
     System.out.println("My Exception 333: ");

      loadNews();
}
private void loadNews(){    
      try{
             BaseFeedParserGiga parser = new BaseFeedParserGiga();
                messages = parser.parsse();
                final String title[]= new String[messages.size()] ;
                final String pubdate[]= new String[messages.size()] ;
                final String link[]= new String[messages.size()] ;
                final String Long[]= new String[messages.size()] ;
                final String image[]= new String[messages.size()] ;
                list = new ArrayList<String>(messages.size());
                mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
                for (com.example.newsworld.MessageGiga msg : messages){
                    list.add(msg.getTitle());
                    title[j]=msg.getTitle();
                    pubdate[i]=msg.getPubdate();
                    link[m]=msg.getLink();
                    Long[l]=msg.getDesc();
                    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(Long[l]);
                     Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("img");
                     String src = links.attr("src");
                    image[k]=src;       
                 setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(GigaActivity.this, R.layout.rows, list ){
                            @Override
                            public View getView(final int j, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                                            View row;
                                            ViewHolder holder;      
                                            if (convertView == null) {
                                                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
                                                    System.out.println("My Exception 5: ");
                                                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                                                    holder.txtclick= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                                                    holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                                                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                                            } else {
                                                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                                            }
                                            String s=image[j];

                                            holder.txtTitle.setText(title[j]+"\n\n"+pubdate[j]);
                                            holder.txtclick.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()
                                               {
                                                    public void onClick(View viewParam)
                                                    {
                                                    Intent in = new Intent(GigaActivity.this,GigaPage.class);
                                                 in.putExtra("title", title[j]);
                                                 in.putExtra("pubdate", pubdate[j]);
                                                 in.putExtra("link", link[j]);
                                              startActivity(in);
                                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.grow_from_middle,R.anim.shrink_to_middle);   
                                                    }
                                                   });
                                            return convertView;
                             }  

                            class ViewHolder {
                                    TextView txtLat;
                                    TextView txtTitle; 
                                    TextView txtPubdate; 
                                    ImageView txtLink;
                                    TextView txtclick;
                            }
                    });  

                         j++;
                         i++;
                         m++;
                         l++;
                         k++;
                    }

           }catch(Exception exc){
               System.out.println("My Exception : "+exc.getMessage());
           }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a field Hashmap

```
HashMap<String,com.example.newsworld.MessageGiga> messages=new HashMap<String,com.example.newsworld.MessageGiga>();
```

in for loop

```
   for (com.example.newsworld.MessageGiga msg : messages){
messages.put(msg.getTitle(),msg);

}
```

send it in a intent as a extra, make sure that your message is serialized

```
intent.putExtra("messages",messages);
```

And in GigaPage get it like this

```
if (getIntent().getSerializableExtra("messages") != null)
            messages= (HashMap<String, com.example.newsworld.MessageGiga>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("messages");
```

You are also sending list that you have used to populate your listview

First get the index of selected item like  this

```
 int index = yourlist.indexOf(title)  //here title is selected item title
```

Get the Data of current title like this

```
com.example.newsworld.MessageGiga  msg=messges.get(ttile);
```

it will return the message object that contains all the information of the message related title

For the onClick of **previous** reduce the index like this

```
index=index-1;
title=yourlist.get(index);
com.example.newsworld.MessageGiga  msg=messges.get(ttile);
```

Do the same for **next** increment the index va;ue

Answer (score 0):

I think I would layout the B page, as you suggest, just as a collection of TextViews with some arrows either side hooking up their onClick method to retrieve the appropriate object by getting it's index by traversing the cursor behind the listview of page A. I would maybe also have the side swipe gesture do the same thing.

```
ViewGroup pageB = (ViewGroup) ViewGroup.inflate(this, R.layout.pageB, null);
TextView textView = (TextView) pageB.findViewById(R.id.a_text_view);

listViewAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, listCursor, tableFromColumns, toListItemViews, 0);
listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    listCursor.moveToPosition(position);
        textView.setText(listCursor.getString(0)); //set textview on pageB with record data
        setContentView(pageB);
    }
});

void onClickNextRecord() {
    listCursor.moveToNext(); // go to next record
    textView.setText(listCursor.getString(0)); //update textview on pageB with next record data
}
```

Comment: Thanks..I am able to show that particular item records on textViews but how to change them on Prev/Next button click....Can you show me some code...!